# Laravel Filament dashboard layout troubles

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-filament, filamentphp

I'm using Laravel Filament v3 in my Laravel 10 application. I'm trying to build a dashboard with some widgets and am struggling to get the layout I desire and need some help.

I'd like my date filters along the top which they are, then I want two cards (customer churn and lifetime) sat next to each other taking up 50% of the screen, then the third row I want 33% 3x cards for Total customers, domains and monitors, then finally, I want all of my graphs taking up 50%. Right now it doesn't look great.

As an example, here's my KeyMetricsOverview stat file

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Widgets;

use Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget as BaseWidget;
use Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget\Stat;

class KeyMetricsOverview extends BaseWidget
{
    protected static ?int $sort = 1;

    protected int | string | array $columnSpan = [
        'md' => 6,
    ];

    protected function getStats(): array
    {
        return [
            Stat::make('Customer churn', '5.45%')
                ->description('57.5%')
                ->descriptionIcon('heroicon-m-arrow-trending-up')
                ->color('danger'),
            Stat::make('Avg. customer lifetime', '18.333 months')
                ->description('-36.51%')
                ->descriptionIcon('heroicon-m-arrow-trending-up')
                ->color('danger'),

        ];
    }
}
```

Then my MetricsOverview:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Widgets;

use Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget as BaseWidget;
use Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget\Stat;

class MetricsOverview extends BaseWidget
{
    protected static ?int $sort = 2;

    protected int | string | array $columnSpan = [
        'md' => 3,
        'xl' => 3,
    ];

    protected function getStats(): array
    {
        return [
            Stat::make('Total customers', '100')
                ->description('69.52%')
                ->descriptionIcon('heroicon-m-arrow-trending-up')
                ->color('danger'),
            Stat::make('Domains', '130')
                ->description('-36.51%')
                ->descriptionIcon('heroicon-m-arrow-trending-up')
                ->color('danger'),
            Stat::make('Monitors', '130')
                ->description('-36.51%')
                ->descriptionIcon('heroicon-m-arrow-trending-up')
                ->color('danger'),
        ];
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your column span
use as this

```
public function getColumns(): int | string | array
{
    return [
        'md' => 4,
        'xl' => 5,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? That gives me an error: `Declaration of App\Filament\Widgets\MetricsOverview::getColumns(): array|string|int must be compatible with Filament\Widgets\StatsOverviewWidget::getColumns(): int`. Remember... `MetricsOverview` is a widget that shows on my dashboard